Why does the 'print' statemnet while using patch for mock test not work?
My original code undergoes the same issue, but this is a shorter version with the same problem/
Here's the code:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import io

def greet_user(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

class TestGreetUser(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def test_with_patch(self, mock_stdout):
        
        greet_user("Alice")
        print("OUTPUT WITH PATCH:")
        print(mock_stdout.getvalue()) #trying to print what was on the console

        
    def test_without_patch(self):
        
        print("OUTPUT WITHOUT PATCH:")
        greet_user("Alice")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

The output is as follows:
.OUTPUT WITHOUT PATCH:
Hello, Alice!
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.011s

OK

Why do I get no value when I try to do it with patch ? What I understand is that when using the patch the output printed to the console is 'redirected' to mock_stdout , but why can't I print the value?

I don't even know what patch is, but I surmise from your code it is some tool to perform tome unit test on your code, while replacing (patching) an object by another. So, it is its whole point (if I surmise correctly) to replace the normal printing why its (sys.stdout is the stream that goes on the console. So, you can't print, because you removed the print. I would imagine that you could keep your own copy of stdout, and use it instead, when you want to really print on the console, despite your asking to capture the print on the console.

That came across my mind, but apparently the 'patch' function only maps the output for 'print' statements that are present in the function to be tested. But I have seen your answer and  will implement it

All the print statements in that function write to the StringIO object, not just the one in greet_user. Try using an assert statement to examine the contents of that object:
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
def test_with_patch(self, mock_stdout):

    greet_user("Alice")
    print("OUTPUT WITH PATCH:")
    #print(mock_stdout.getvalue()) #trying to print what was on the console
    assert False, mock_stdout.getvalue()

The test will fail, and the traceback will include the contents of mock_stdout.
If you really only want to patch it for greet_user, use a context manager instead of decorating the test.
def test_with_patch(self):
    with patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO) as mock_stdout:
        greet_user("Alice")
    print("OUTPUT WITH PATCH:")
    print(mock_stdout.getvalue()) #trying to print what was on the console


Even tho I just discovered patch with this question, I couldn't resist trying if what I suggested in comments works. It does
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import io
import sys

def greet_user(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

mystdout = sys.stdout

class TestGreetUser(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def test_with_patch(self, mock_stdout):
        
        greet_user("Alice")
        print("OUTPUT WITH PATCH:")
        mystdout.write("«"+mock_stdout.getvalue()+"»") #trying to print what was on the console

        
    def test_without_patch(self):
        
        print("OUTPUT WITHOUT PATCH:")
        greet_user("Alice")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

So, using mystdout.write bypasses the capture of sys.stdout by patch.
(btw, what you did was some very dangerous recursion... print(whatIamprinting) can be endless...)

Where do you think recursion occurs?

It doesn't, obviously. Otherwise OP would be still waiting for is code to stop — or would have reported a crash). I am not talking of a recursive call. Just of a recursive question. Saying that you want to print what ever you print is recursive (the word "recursion" is not limited to recursive function — I feel that you believe that I believe, that there are some recursive calls somewhere there). But, I maintain that trying to print on stdout everything that was printed on stdout is a recursive, endless will. My point is: if it worked, that would be endless.
